# Electron application can't resolve 'greenworks-linux32' on Steamworks integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, steam, steamworks-api

I have html5 application built for desktop with Electron. I currently try to integrate Greenworks SDK for Steamworks SDK to support achievements in it.

I tried both electron-rebuild and node-gyp ways to integrate Greenworks resulted in the same error - application crashes on startup with a problem in module resolving - "greenworks-linux32.node cannot be found”.

I tried to download this file separately and put it in greenworks/lib. But the problem persists. I also tried to put whole greenworks folder in the same folder with script that calls Greenworks API.

I use the following build:

```
Greenworks: [v0.10.0 x64]
Steamworks SDK: [v1.40]
Electron: [v1.6.15]
```

Folder structure is as follows:

```
app/
  steam_appid.txt
  node_modules/
    greenworks/
      greenworks.js
      lib/
        greenworks-linux32.node
        greenworks-linux64.node
        greenworks-osx64.node
        greenworks-win32.node
        greenworks-win64.node
        libsdkencryptedappticket.dylib
        libsdkencryptedappticket.so
        libsdkencryptedappticket64.so
        libsteam_api.dylib
        libsteam_api.so
        libsteam_api64.so
        sdkencryptedappticket.dll
        sdkencryptedappticket.lib
        sdkencryptedappticket64.dll
        sdkencryptedappticket64.lib
        steam_api.dll
        steam_api.lib
        steam_api64.dll
        steam_api64.lib

  public/
    index.html
  electron/
```

Please share any thoughts on what could it be. I have an idea that the problem caused. The problem appears only when I'm calling Greenworks API.
I used this guide to proceed: https://github.com/greenheartgames/greenworks/blob/master/docs/build-instructions-electron.md

Comment: Please share the code of requiring `greenworks`.

Comment: As for the variant of importing as a node module
var greenworks = require('greenworks');

For the variant where greenworks placed in the same folder 
var greenworks = require('./greenworks');

Comment: @Merkulov I have a similar problem. Did you even find an answer? Thank you.